# Need help to convert a class to XML and then a bytearray

Tags: wcf-rest

I thought this would be an easy task but I seem to have gotten lost in a rabbit hole.

I am trying to convert a class to XML and then a byte array in order to send it as the content of a HTTPWebRequest for a WCF Restful webservice. My code will return the class as XML in the Byte Array but the format is incorrect. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><FirstName>Richard</FirstName><LastName>Cranium</LastName></Person>
```

I was attempting to use the OmitXmlDeclaration method thinking this would eliminate the extra declarations but it does not work with the xmltextwriter object and when I use the xmlwriterobject I can't determine how convert the outcome to a Byte array.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Shared Function GenerateXMLPersonAsByte(strFirstName As String, strLastName As String) As Byte()
    ' This should serialize this to a byte array

    Dim p As New Person()
    p.FirstName = strFirstName
    p.LastName = strLastName

    ' Want to use this with the xmlTextWriter but it does not support the property it is to be used with the XMLWriter instead
    'Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
    'settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True
    'settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    'settings.CloseOutput = False

    ' Create the XmlWriter object and write some content. 
    Dim mStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim ser As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Person))
    Dim xmlTW As New XmlTextWriter(mStream, Encoding.UTF8)
    ser.Serialize(xmlTW, p)
    mStream = DirectCast(xmlTW.BaseStream, MemoryStream)

    mStream.Close()
    Return mStream.ToArray()

End Function
```

What must I do in order to get the XML with the correct opening tag?
or 
How do I get the output from the XmlTextWriter object to a byte array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer the whole question, but convert to string first

```
Dim myXmlString As String   
Dim myStringWriter As New StringWriter()
Dim myXmlTextWriter As XmlTextWriter = New XmlTextWriter(myStringWriter)
'Write XML, and then flush the writer...
myXmlTextWriter.Flush() 
'Return text from string writer...
myXmlString = myStringWriter.ToString()
'Close the Objects...
myStringWriter.Close()
myXmlTextWriter.Close()
```

then convert to byte using (sorry, C#, but you get the .NET call)

```
byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myXmlString);
```

Comment: That worked Thank you unfortunately my code removes the XML declaration part that is prior to the person start tag but the line that follows the person start tag (Being: xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"") is still there. Any idea as how I can get rid of this?

Comment: Did you try this? look at last entry, which sets null namespaces. http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/809956-how-remove-xmlns-xsd-root-tag-via-xmlserialization